# Display Mixed Content in SharePoint hosted Silverlight app with reverse-proxy

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, load-balancing, reverse-proxy

I have a SharePoint site that is available via the internet. Internally, the http request is routed to an https reauest and the SSL is offloaded on our load balancer/reverse proxy device. Everything is working well, except for a Silverlight application.

This applicaiton is hosted on one of the pages and when the page loads in the browser it connects to a SharePoint list to retrieve its data. At this point, IE pops up a window saying "Display Mixed Content". Obviously, it thinks there is a mix of http and https content on the page.

Does this mean I am going to have to host the web service via SSL (and just pass it through to the SharePoint server) and not let the reverse-proxy handle it? Or, what is the workaround for this type of scenario?

Comment: I changed the Silverlight APP uses to use "https" instead of "http". For obvious reasons, this doesn't get changed when the site is accessed externally. Now, my dilemna is... how do I kow when the Silverlight App is being run from outside our network (and needs the "https") and when it is being run internally...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used to solve this problem:

> _siteURL = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.DocumentUri.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith("https:")
>   ? SP.ApplicationContext.Current.Url.Replace("http", "https") :
>   SP.ApplicationContext.Current.Url;

This allows my Silverlight app to work on our SharePoint (extended) Forms Based site externally (through our F5/Reverse Proxy) and internally.